# Client/Server web base application for windows

Tags: client-server, windows, windows-server, windows-client

I want some suggestion from you. I want to create a system application which should be based on client/server. When client(may be more than one) input any data it should be store on my server. For this i don't know which language I've to use for front end and what should be in back-end. Please can you give me some idea about it. Simply I want to take input **Name** and **Roll** from client and store it on my server. And whenever client want to display they can use the display button to display it.

Thanks and waiting for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah you can use java language and transmit your data from client to server as well sever to client. 
if Locally you want you can use php and make your system server by using any server like **(wamp server, xamp server)**. 
Hope this will help you and others.

If you want mobile application you can use android also. By using php you can make **API** and handle it through android **get, post** method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java language, and transmit the data between the client and server using JSON(JavaScript Object notation) objects. It will help you serialise your objects(Data you want to transfer) into bytes and transmission will be efficient.

It is easier to put data into a JSON object using respective keys. Ex:
JSONObject.put("key","value");

And, henceforth you can parse them on the server side.Ex.:JSONParser class

You can use json.simple library to do so and it will make your code a lot more efficient and serialised.